# How to set fliers in matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot

I'm using python to create boxplots seen here:

[image]

The filers are 'o' markers, but the width of the circles are too thick.

I want to know how to show hollow instead of solid dots.

Comment: hi please be more specific about the question and if your question is more towards maths, you can ask in this forum https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Here's an example on the main matplotlib example gallery that shows how to customize the flier in a boxplot https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html